# Can't connect to ftp port 21

Tags: windows, ftp, windows-firewall

I installed ftp server on Windows 2003, enabled 21 port in Firewall and I can connect "telnet localhost 21" but can't connect "telnet 77.168.0.1 21"

What it can be?

Comment: What's the output from netstat -an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check that the IP address you're trying to connect on is the correct one.

Ensure that the windows firewall is allowing port 21 connections on that IP address.

Check also that your ftp daemon is listening on 77.168.0.1.

If you're trying to connect from a different computer to 77.168.0.1 then ensure that there is no firewall in the route.

Comment: 1 - IP is right, "telnet 77.168.0.1 80" works ok, problem is with 21 port

Comment: 2 - I turned off windows firewall and same problem

Comment: 3 - How to check that ftp daemon is listening on 77.168.0.1 ??? Ftp service is running, "telnet localhost 21" or "telnet 127.0.0.1 21" works

Comment: @ihorko: netstat -an | findstr ":21" should have a line that contains something like `77.168.0.1:21` if you're listening on port 21

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your external router/firewall isn't mapping port 21 down to that server, whether by nat, policies, mip, or whatever method you want to use.  Check your wan firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Also check that 77.168.0.1 is a local address, that its plumbed and the interface is up. Paste the output of

```
netstat /rnv
ipconfig /all
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `telnet 77.168.0.1 21` from the server itself - that way you can check if it is running on this address.